# Non-British mother with British kids

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

I'm Jamaican, but I have three children who were born British through their father. We are no longer together, but I would like to take my kids to the UK and settle there. Can I settle in the UK as a Jamaican with my only ties being through my children?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are not British (and being Jamaican makes determining that a little confusing and likely depends on your family circumstances prior to 1962), then it will be difficult to settle in the UK. You would probably be looking at a [applying as a parent for a family visa](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/parent), but that requires your children to be under 18 and living in the UK. Unless you have a way for your children to live in the UK prior to you settling there, the family visa will not work. This then leaves you having to immigrate based on *standard* routes that do not consider the nationality of your children.